# How to check the test coverage in java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I want to check the test coverage, run through run `Test in'lesson_3` with coverage. I get an error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:66)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:64)
    ... 11 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Process finished with exit code 1
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stack trace you are affected by [IDEA-177038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177038) which is marked as a duplicate of [IDEABKL-5941](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941).

The known workaround is to add following to the command line arguments:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Temp
```